# renaming docker0 virtual bridge name to something else

Tags: docker, nic

I am curious if it is possible to rename "docker0" virtual bridge name to something else. Where does the Docker engine get "docker0" name from?

Comment: The docker website and man pages have quite a lot of documentation about networking.  You might want to check those first.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new bridge with any name you want, lets sat bridge0. Then you can set DOCKER_OPTS="-b=bridge0" and start the docker daemon. Put the DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker

For more info an details, check this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/